# Docusign API - Self Signing

Tags: docusignapi

We have a requirement where we need to make a couple of PDF forms available using a HTML link to users for signing, but the signer should be a self-signer.  In other words, once the signer completes signing using Docusign, they should be able to download the signed documents.  However, we as the sender if the HTML link don't want to receive these saved documents as they have Personally Identifiable Information.  The signer will upload these documents separately into our application at a later point.

I searched, but couldn't find a way to generate a HTML link for a self-signer. I was able to create a prototype that works for a regular signer, but not for a self-signer.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Here's my code right snippet now:

```
        // specify the document we want signed
        string SignTest1File = @"C:\Users\skosuri.AA\Desktop\of0306.pdf";

        string SignTest2File = @"C:\Users\skosuri.AA\Desktop\epa-credit-release-authorization.pdf";

        // Enter recipient (signer) name and email address
        string recipientName = "Chris";
        string recipientEmail = "xxx.xxx@epa.gov";

        // instantiate api client with appropriate environment (for production change to www.docusign.net/restapi)
        string basePath = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

        // instantiate a new api client
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);

        // set client in global config so we don't need to pass it to each API object
        Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

        string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + Username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + IntegratorKey + "\"}";
        Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

        // we will retrieve this from the login() results
        string accountId = null;

        // the authentication api uses the apiClient (and X-DocuSign-Authentication header) that are set in Configuration object
        AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
        LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

        // user might be a member of multiple accounts
        accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

        Console.WriteLine("LoginInformation: {0}", loginInfo.ToJson());

        // Read a file from disk to use as a document
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(SignTest1File);

        byte[] fileBytes2 = File.ReadAllBytes(SignTest2File);

        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envDef.EmailSubject = "Please complete and sign these documents";

        // Add a document to the envelope
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
        doc.Name = "of0306.pdf";
        doc.DocumentId = "1";
        doc.TransformPdfFields = "true";


        envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
        envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

        // Add a second document to the envelope
        Document doc2 = new Document();
        doc2.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes2);
        doc2.Name = "epa-credit-release-authorization.pdf";
        doc2.DocumentId = "2";
        doc2.TransformPdfFields = "true";

        envDef.Documents.Add(doc2);

        // Add a recipient to sign the documeent
        Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.Name = recipientName;
        signer.Email = recipientEmail;
        signer.RecipientId = "1";
        signer.DefaultRecipient = "true";

        // must set |clientUserId| to embed the recipient
        signer.ClientUserId = "1234";

        // Create a |SignHere| tab on the document for the recipient to sign
        signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
        signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned>();
        signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs = new List<FullName>();

        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();

        signHere.AnchorString = "Applicant's Signature:";
        signHere.AnchorXOffset = "1.5";
        signHere.AnchorYOffset = "0";
        signHere.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "false";
        signHere.AnchorUnits = "inches";
        signHere.DocumentId = "1";
        signHere.RecipientId = "1";
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

        DateSigned ds = new DateSigned();
        ds.PageNumber = "3";
        ds.XPosition = "380";
        ds.YPosition = "550";
        ds.DocumentId = "1";
        ds.RecipientId = "1";
        ds.TabLabel = "Date Signed";
        signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(ds);

        // Create a |SignHere| tab on the second document for the recipient to sign

        SignHere signHere2 = new SignHere();


        signHere2.PageNumber = "1";
        signHere2.XPosition = "80";
        signHere2.YPosition = "375";
        signHere2.DocumentId = "2";
        signHere2.RecipientId = "1";
        signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere2);

        FullName fn = new FullName();
        fn.PageNumber = "1";
        fn.XPosition = "80";
        fn.YPosition = "300";
        fn.DocumentId = "2";
        fn.RecipientId = "1";
        signer.Tabs.FullNameTabs.Add(fn);

        DateSigned ds2 = new DateSigned();
        ds2.PageNumber = "1";
        ds2.XPosition = "80";
        ds2.YPosition = "475";
        ds2.DocumentId = "2";
        ds2.RecipientId = "1";
        signer.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(ds2);



        envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
        envDef.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

        // set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
        envDef.Status = "sent";

        // Use the EnvelopesApi to create and send the signature request
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);


        Console.WriteLine("EnvelopeSummary:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelopeSummary));

        RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
        {
            ReturnUrl = "https://www.epa.gov",
            ClientUserId = "1234",  // must match clientUserId set in step #2!
            AuthenticationMethod = "email",
            UserName = recipientName,
            Email = recipientEmail
        };

        // create the recipient view (aka signing URL)
        ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);

        // print the JSON response
        Console.WriteLine("ViewUrl:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recipientView));

        // Start the embedded signing session!
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(recipientView.Url);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your question.

Your app can use a "system user" (an email account such as "noreply@company.com") as the sender and present an embedded signing request to the "self-signer."

That way the "self-signer" can fill in the information and sign.

The signed document will only be visible (via DocuSign) to the system user. You can also set up a purge policy.

But it is not a friendly user experience to ask that the

> signer will upload these documents separately into our application at a later point.

Instead, I suggest that you check out the `concealValueOnDocument` parameter of the text (data) tab.

Docs:

> When set to true, the field appears normally while the recipient is adding or modifying the information in the field, but the data is not visible (the characters are hidden by asterisks) to any other signer or the sender.
>
> When an envelope is completed the information is available to the sender through the Form Data link in the DocuSign Console.
>   This setting applies only to text boxes and does not affect list boxes, radio buttons, or check boxes.

Using this setting enables the signer to see the PII when they sign, but the information is not visible to subsequent signers or viewers of the information.

The PII data is still available via the API so your integration can process it as necessary.